# Telerik ASP.NET, autocomplete RadTextbox

Tags: asp.net, telerik

How do i implement an autocomplete RadTextbox? I have a string[] but how do i link this to the RadTextbox? Documentation on Telerik site is really brief and i can't seem to find other stuff about it on the net.

Answer (score 1):

I think they utilize the RadComboBox as the means for autocomplete, rather than the textbox: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/autocompleteclientside/defaultcs.aspx

I could be wrong, but I haven't seen much with the RadTextBox in terms of auto complete; you may be able to link it to the AutoCompleteExtender in the ajax control toolkit...

HTH.

Comment: Yep, I used the RadComboBox instead of the Textbox. I tried to use the AutoCompleteExtender but I gave up since the RadComboBox was easier to implement! 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to let the user type and select from a known set of values?  If so you want to use the RadComboBox and set the MarkFirstMatch propety to true.

If you want to allow the user to type in and select from an unknown set of values, possibly pulled from a database (think typing in google search), you will need to look at writing some AJAX javascript to handle the client side event (maybe OnValueChanged??).  You will need to call a WS and get the values that match your critera, then somehow show them in the client.  As mentioned above you may be able to use the AutoCompleteExtender from the AJAX Control Toolkit to help.